# I am unable to edit email message body in evolution following update

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, evolution

I updated my system and now when I open an email to send, I can add header information but not the body of the message.
Same with trying to reply to an email. No cursor will parse to the body of the message. It's read only.

How do I re-enable my message body in evolution?

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.10"
```

evolution version

```
3.40.4-1ubuntu2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 evolution
```

will fix the issue. (from #evolution on GIMPnet)

Bug report filed here

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=241188